# I am new to FPGA design, When I finished my design,How could I make my design became a real chip?

Tags: windows, generics, fpga, microchip

I am new to FPGA design, When I finished my design,
How could I make my design became a real chip?

Answer (score 0):

---

*When I finished my design, How could I make my design became a real chip?*

---

You need to generate a FPGA [bitstream](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitstream). A bitstream includes the description of the hardware logic, routing, and initial values for both registers and on-chip memory blocks. This particular bitstream file is more than the bits to configure an FPGA. It also has certain human-readable fields to describe those bits and it also has an assembly-like instruction set to describe the FPGA configuration process.

Answer (score 0):

There are two routes you can take (ignoring the option to buy separate transistors/discrete ICs and lots of soldering) the easiest is to find an FPGA(devboard) that matches your requirements and then using the vendors' recommended tool to generate and configure the FPGA. You may need to make small changes to your design to make it fit/better utilize the available resources.

The other (way-way-more-expensive-but-cheap-when-needing-millions-of-chips) is to go the [ASIC](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application-specific_integrated_circuit) way. I wouldn't recommend that to someone who is new though.